# Generalized Schur-Weyl Duality

Tags: representation-theory

[Schur-Weyl duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Weyl_duality) relates representations of the symmetric group to representations of $GL(n)$.  Is there a generalization to arbitrary reductive groups?

Comment: For $O(n)$ and $Sp(n)$, the algebra on the other side of the Schur-Weyl duality (replacing the group algebra $kS_n$) is called Brauer algebra, first studied in [H.Wenzl - On the structure of Brauer's centralizer algebras];  Goodman-Wallach's book also has an account on this subject.  I don't know about general theory for reductive group though.

Comment: I guess as Wenzl points out in his paper, Brauer first studied those centralizer algebras in [R. BRAUER, On algebras which are connected with the semisimple continuous groups, Ann. of Math. 38 (1937), 854-872]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Aaron has pointed out, there are generalizations of the Schur-Weyl duality to certain reductive groups. But as far as I know, there is no unified theory. [This paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.1877.pdf) of Stephen Doty seems to give a good overview of what can be done (although it is most probably not exhausting).